Can't install vmware workstation 17.5 in slackware current
I can't install vmware workstation profesional 17.5 in my Slackware current, this is the error:
root@r2d2:/home/fito/Downloads# sh VMware-Workstation-Full-17.5.0-22583795.x86_64.bundle 
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Installing VMware VMX 17.5.0
    Configuring...--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):####                                 ]  52%
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/python/lib/logging/__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2018' in position 950: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer.py", line 694, in <module>
    main(options)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer.py", line 536, in main
    txn.Install(options.installComponent,
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/transaction.py", line 687, in Install
    RunTransaction(actions, options)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/transaction.py", line 414, in RunTransaction
    RunThreadedTransaction(txn, actions)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/transaction.py", line 472, in RunThreadedTransaction
    txn.Run()
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/transaction.py", line 78, in Run
    self.get()()
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/common.py", line 156, in Show
    wrap(i.PostTransaction, txn.opts['ignoreErrors'])
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/util/__init__.py", line 26, in wrap
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/install.py", line 308, in PostTransaction
    self._installer.PostTransactionInstall(**self.args)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/remoteinstaller.py", line 94, in PostTransactionInstall
    return self.MessageOut(self.whoami(), old, new, upgrade)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/remoteinstaller.py", line 387, in MessageOut
    retval = vmispy.RunExternalMethod(self._remoteUID, 0, strio.getvalue().decode('latin-1'))
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/installer.py", line 122, in MessageIn
    self.proxyObject.MessageIn(uid, str)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/remoteinstallerops.py", line 403, in MessageIn
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 372, in PostTransactionInstall
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/installer.py", line 40, in Info
    return self.installer.Log('info', *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/installer.py", line 335, in Log
    return self.proxyObject.Log(logType, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/remoteinstallerops.py", line 159, in Log
    return self.MessageOut(self.whoami(), logType, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/remoteinstallerops.py", line 485, in MessageOut
    retval = vmispy.RunExternalMethod(0, self._UID, strio.getvalue().decode('latin-1'))
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/remoteinstaller.py", line 301, in MessageIn
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/installer.py", line 335, in Log
    return self.proxyObject.Log(logType, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/vmis.lbeQOf/install/vmware-installer/vmis/core/localinstallerops.py", line 241, in Log
    ltype(*args, **kwargs)
Message: 'stderr: [AppLoader] Use shipped PC/SC Lite smart card framework.\nAn up-to-date "pcsc-lite-libs" or "libpcsclite1" package from your system is preferred.\n[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.\nUsing kernel build system.\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: \'naked\' return found in MITIGATION_RETHUNK build\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Free() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Add()\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()\nIn file included from /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:76:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/pgtbl.h: In function \u2018PgtblVa2MPNLocked\u2019:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/pgtbl.h:60:8: error: implicit declaration of function \u2018pgd_large\u2019; did you mean \u2018pgd_page\u2019? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]\n   60 |    if (pgd_large(*pgd)) {\n      |        ^~~~~~~~~\n      |        pgd_page\nIn file included from /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/pgtbl.h:25:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_pgtable.h:39:45: error: implicit declaration of function \u2018p4d_large\u2019; did you mean \u2018p4d_page\u2019? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]\n   39 | #   define compat_p4d_large(p4d)            p4d_large(p4d)\n      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/pgtbl.h:70:8: note: in expansion of macro \u2018compat_p4d_large\u2019\n   70 |    if (compat_p4d_large(*p4d)) {\n      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/pgtbl.h:78:11: error: implicit declaration of function \u2018pud_large\u2019; did you mean \u2018pud_page\u2019? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]\n   78 |       if (pud_large(*pud)) {\n      |           ^~~~~~~~~\n      |           pud_page\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/task.c:548:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  548 | TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment(void)\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/./include/pgtbl.h:86:14: error: implicit declaration of function \u2018pmd_large\u2019; did you mean \u2018pmd_page\u2019? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]\n   86 |          if (pmd_large(*pmd)) {\n      |              ^~~~~~~~~\n      |              pmd_page\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: At top level:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:2926:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018HostIFCheckTrackedMPN\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n 2926 | HostIFCheckTrackedMPN(VMDriver *vm, // IN: The VM instance\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nIn file included from /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:52:\n./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h: In function \u2018random_get_entropy\u2019:\n./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:12:24: error: implicit declaration of function \u2018random_get_entropy_fallback\u2019; did you mean \u2018random_get_entropy\u2019? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]\n   12 |                 return random_get_entropy_fallback();\n      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n      |                        random_get_entropy\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3046:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018HostIFWritePhysicalWork\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n 3046 | HostIFWritePhysicalWork(MA ma,             // MA to be written to\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3205:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018HostIFStartTimer\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n 3205 | HostIFStartTimer(Bool rateChanged,  //IN: Did rate change?\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c: At top level:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:700:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018Vmx86FreeVMDriver\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  700 | Vmx86FreeVMDriver(VMDriver *vm)\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:733:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018Vmx86AllocVMDriver\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  733 | Vmx86AllocVMDriver(uint32 numVCPUs)\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nmake[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:244: /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1\nmake[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:271:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018LinuxDriverInit\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  271 | LinuxDriverInit(void)\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:339:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018LinuxDriverExit\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  339 | LinuxDriverExit(void)\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nmake[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:244: /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o] Error 1\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section\nmake[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-6.9.3/Makefile:1919: /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmmon-only] Error 2\nmake[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2\nmake: *** [Makefile:117: vmmon.ko] Error 2\nUsing kernel build system.\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/userif.c:1091:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018VNetUserIf_Create\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n 1091 | VNetUserIf_Create(VNetPort **ret) // OUT\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/netif.c:173:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018VNetNetIf_Create\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  173 | VNetNetIf_Create(char *devName,  // IN:\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c:258:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018VNetBridge_Create\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n  258 | VNetBridge_Create(const char *devName, // IN:  name of device (e.g., "eth0")\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nIn file included from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:305,\n                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:2138,\n                 from /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c:25:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c: In function \u2018VNetBridgeReceiveFromVNet\u2019:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h:44:39: error: \u2018dev_base_lock\u2019 undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean \u2018device_lock\u2019?\n   44 | #define dev_lock_list()    read_lock(&dev_base_lock)\n      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n./include/linux/rwlock.h:56:48: note: in definition of macro \u2018read_lock\u2019\n   56 | #define read_lock(lock)         _raw_read_lock(lock)\n      |                                                ^~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c:587:4: note: in expansion of macro \u2018dev_lock_list\u2019\n  587 |    dev_lock_list();\n      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h:44:39: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in\n   44 | #define dev_lock_list()    read_lock(&dev_base_lock)\n      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n./include/linux/rwlock.h:56:48: note: in definition of macro \u2018read_lock\u2019\n   56 | #define read_lock(lock)         _raw_read_lock(lock)\n      |                                                ^~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c:587:4: note: in expansion of macro \u2018dev_lock_list\u2019\n  587 |    dev_lock_list();\n      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/userif.o: warning: objtool: VNetCsumCopyDatagram+0x52: call to csum_partial_copy_nocheck() with UACCESS enabled\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c: In function \u2018VNetBridgeUp\u2019:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h:44:39: error: \u2018dev_base_lock\u2019 undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean \u2018device_lock\u2019?\n   44 | #define dev_lock_list()    read_lock(&dev_base_lock)\n      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n./include/linux/rwlock.h:56:48: note: in definition of macro \u2018read_lock\u2019\n   56 | #define read_lock(lock)         _raw_read_lock(lock)\n      |                                                ^~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c:900:4: note: in expansion of macro \u2018dev_lock_list\u2019\n  900 |    dev_lock_list();\n      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c: At top level:\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1411:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018VNetBridgeSendLargePacket\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n 1411 | VNetBridgeSendLargePacket(struct sk_buff *skb,        // IN: packet to split\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nmake[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:244: /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1\nmake[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....\n/tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:87:1: warning: no previous prototype for \u2018VNetUserListener_Create\u2019 [-Wmissing-prototypes]\n   87 | VNetUserListener_Create(uint32 classMask,  // IN: the listener\'s class mask\n      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nmake[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-6.9.3/Makefile:1919: /tmp/modconfig-bzphMU/vmnet-only] Error 2\nmake[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2\nmake: *** [Makefile:117: vmnet.ko] Error 2\nUnable to install all modules.  See log for details.\n\n'
Installing VMware Workstation 17.5.0
    Configuring...
[######################################################################] 100%

I have the lastest kernel 6.9.3 and the headers, source and all dependencies, i think so.
Can you help me!!

Your kernel modules failed building.
Version 17.5.0 is really outdated, please try version 17.5.2.
If it still doesn't work/build, use this repo which contains patches for VMWare host modules for modern Linux kernels.
